# Use specific Weblogic managed server from java ee application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, cluster-computing

1. If I have two java ee applications (Application A and B) in the same domain of web-logic cluster server with two managed servers, is it possible to call Application B **running in a specific managed server**(Can I choose the managed server?) from application A?
2. If I have just one java ee application deployed in a domain of web-logic cluster server with two managed servers(MS A and B), is it possible to call or start the application in the managed server B from application in the managed server A?

Answer (score 0):

For #1, please provide more information on how Application A is going to call Application B.  Is it EJB or REST or something else?

For #2, yes.  Managed servers can be started using WLST scripting so you should be able to incorporate that logic into the other managed server, for example by having it invoke a script from its shell that contains the required WLST logic.